# Logistic regression in python with a dataframe of arrays

Tags: python, pandas, regression

I am trying to perform a logistic regression with X being a dataframe of 816 arrays (each one sized 1024)  and y1 being a dataframe of 816 True/False values as shown here:

[image]

I cant find a similar example (with array as argument)
Trying to do

```
from sklearn.linear_model import LogisticRegression
model = LogisticRegression()
model.fit(y, y1)
```

i get and error

ValueError: setting an array element with a sequence

Probably this is a very basic question, having to do with the fact that a single value is expected instead of an array, but any idea how should i be doing this?

Comment: What is a "vector", neither `pandas` nor `numpy` nor plain python have a type named "vector"

Comment: both are dataframes, edited that

Comment: `X = pd.DataFrame(X.Data.values.tolist(), index= X.index)` then pass it into fit

Comment: that did it, thanks!